# How to circumvent ORA-01775 looping chain of synonyms in Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle

I think I have a database problem... Not necessarily with Oracle Forms (10g)...Let me explain ...

I'm trying to implement [this Oracle Forms Menu Security Configuration](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/forms/11g/formsmenusmanage/formsmenusmanage.htm#t5) When I do it, it says that I get ORA - 01775 "Looping Chain of Synonyms".... Since I have NO IDEA what synonym is creating the problem, I was wondering how you guyz can help me fix this issue.... Maybe there is a DBA script somewhere to solve this....

**UPDATE**

Oracle Database trace  log says the culprit SQL is :

`select ROLE GRPNAME ,FLAG GRPFLG from FRM50_ENABLED_ROLES order by ROLE desc`  and `FRM50_ENABLED_ROLES` is created from [step 1 here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/forms/11g/formsmenusmanage/formsmenusmanage.htm#t5)

That statement executes properly where I execute it in SQL*PLUS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the below event in the database:

```
alter system set events '1775 trace name errorstack level 1';
```

This will make all the ORA-01775 errors logged in the alert log plus a trace file, and that trace fail should contain the `Current SQL` statement, that caused the error.

Comment: Here is the culprit SQL statement `select ROLE GRPNAME ,FLAG GRPFLG  from FRM50_ENABLED_ROLES  order by ROLE desc` How to resolve the issue from here ? `FRM50_ENABLED_ROLES` is a view created [on step 1 here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/forms/11g/formsmenusmanage/formsmenusmanage.htm#t5). It's related to Oracle Forms 10g

Comment: That SELECT statement executes properly where I execute it in SQL*PLUS

Comment: @JasonKrs Then I would double-check the owner, name, type and existence of the objects related to that view/synonym. The view should exist in the SYSTEM schema. The synonym should be a public synonym, with the same name.

Comment: Awesome Balazs... Problem solved... Actually I created the  view with `sys as sysdba` instead of simply using `system`.. So the owner of the object was not correct... Thank you Sir

Comment: I had the same problem. Thank you!!! If you are running RAC you'll want to issue the alter system command on both nodes if you are not sure where the user will be connecting. Also to turn of tracing: alter system set events '1775 trace name context off';